# Enable COD on above specific cart value Woocomerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to enable COD Payment Option only above a certain cart total amount and for anything less than that, it will be disabled.

i searched an found a code but it was opposite, it was disabling COD after the cart total so didn't help

Answer (score -2):

I think that the easiest way to do it is to enable the COD in the WooCommerce Payments settings and disable it if the total is under a certain amount.

The code would look like this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'so_77294316_cod_above_threshold' );
function so_77294316_cod_above_threshold( $_available_gateways ) {
    $minimum_amount = 100; // change this to your minimum amount
    
    if ( WC()->cart->total < $minimum_amount ) {
        unset( $_available_gateways['cod'] );
    }
    
    return $_available_gateways;
}
```